# How to evaluate BOOTP chaddr by mac address?

Tags: networking, mac-address, dhcp

In dhcp packet, a field means client hardware address, but it's not the same as mac address like "fa:16:3e:6f:1a:9d".

If I have known a interface's mac address "fa:16:3e:6f:1a:9d", how to evaluate chaddr by mac address?

```
 0                   1                   2                   3
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |     op (1)    |   htype (1)   |   hlen (1)    |   hops (1)    |
   +---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
   |                            xid (4)                            |
   +-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
   |           secs (2)            |           flags (2)           |
   +-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
   |                          ciaddr  (4)                          |
   +---------------------------------------------------------------+
   |                          yiaddr  (4)                          |
   +---------------------------------------------------------------+
   |                          siaddr  (4)                          |
   +---------------------------------------------------------------+
   |                          giaddr  (4)                          |
   +---------------------------------------------------------------+
   |                                                               |
   |                          chaddr  (16)                         |
   |                                                               |
   |                                                               |
   +---------------------------------------------------------------+
   |                                                               |
   |                          sname   (64)                         |
   +---------------------------------------------------------------+
   |                                                               |
   |                          file    (128)                        |
   +---------------------------------------------------------------+
   |                                                               |
   |                          options (variable)                   |
   +---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

See https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2131.txt

```
4.4.1 Initialization and allocation of network address
...
The client MUST include its hardware address in the 'chaddr'
field, if necessary for delivery of DHCP reply messages.
```

First six bytes contain the hardware address, the rest are zeros. One can inspect the contents of bootp/dhcp packets for example in Linux with dhcpdump.